# "No Calendar has been set" - iOS6 Titanium

Tags: titanium, ios6

Ive tried a number of titanium modules to add an entry into an iPhone calendar, all seem to work fine on my simulator but when I test the app on my phone I get the following error,

> "No Calendar has been set"

as this has happened on 3 different modules I think the issue is with the phone (or titanium), there are some posts about removing calendars and re-adding, rebooting the phone but I still get the same error, interestingly the calender itself works perfectly.

The calendar has a number of what I assume are default calendars and a shared calendar but I dont see how thast makes a difference and in settings one is selected as the default

Answer (score 0):

Do you require the calendarEvent permission (needed from version 6 of iOS)?

See [this this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537984/app-calendar-functionality-no-longer-working-in-ios-6)